# Displaying a String rather than Int

Tags: c#

Currently my code will display results from my database into labels. All of the results I get back are ints. I'd like to change that and make it, for example, 1 would be displayed as "Online".

I know I could write a bunch of "if" statements but that doesn't seem proper. Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: What about using an `enum`?

Comment: Create a  description a table with `ID | Description`, return them both from your query via a join and store them together in a class/tuple etc

Comment: You could use a Dictionary object where the key is the int Id and the value is the text.  It would look something like this:  Dictionary<int, string> values = new Dictionary();  values.Add(1, "Online");

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I think I'm going to go with enums here. Have a good day.

Answer (score 4):

```
enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };
```

Then use

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(Colors), 3)
```

Keeping in mind that enums are zero based, unless a value is specified.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, if you specify the numeric value.  In the example above, they are zero based. @Lloyd The answer I provided is updated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Headspring Enumeration](https://github.com/HeadspringLabs/Enumeration) for this. No reflection, extensible, flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `switch case`, it's much better than a lot of `if` statements in this case.

```
switch(num)
{
    case 1:
        string = "Online";
    case 2:
        string = "Offline";
    default:
        string = "Default"; // Called if none of the cases above are true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a program uses set of inetgral numbers try to use C# enums.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/sbbt4032.aspx 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_enums.htm